# Photoshop: How to edit a shape when select again in its layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Maybe this question seems easily but I don't know why it doesn't obvious in my current Photoshop settings.

1. I select shape tool and draw somethings (such as circle, rectangle ...). I see at this step, I see properties panel for change shape attributes:

[image: toolbar]
[image: toolbar]

2. I select another layers (for doing some work, so I lost focus current shape). And then I choose again new created shape layer. After that I choose `Move Tool` to select shape. I cannot see shape toolbar again for editing. I just see this toolbar:

[image: toolbar]
[image]

And here is my screen after I select `Shape tool`
[image]

My question is: How can I select again shape and show shape toolbar for editing purpose ?

Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adjust rounded rectangle radii without creating a new one in Photoshop C6](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/38825/adjust-rounded-rectangle-radii-without-creating-a-new-one-in-photoshop-c6) or [How to change between Live shapes to masks properties in Photoshop CC](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28107/how-to-change-between-live-shapes-to-masks-properties-in-photoshop-cc)

Comment: @Joonas ahhhhhhhh. very very thank for your link :D :D :D Not 100% duplicate, because I use both two answers in your link to satisfy my issue. Thanks so much :D

Comment: As you can see conversation between me and Scott to understand my problem. just because I'm new to Photoshop and have many things to learn :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially when you draw a primitive (rectangle, ellipse) you get the properties for that primitive. These are called "live shapes" in Adobe terms.

If you transform the shape, via free transform, it get's "baked in" and it is no longer a primitive or "Live Shape". It gets expanded, for lack of a better term, into a standard shape which is no longer "live". Customarily there is a warning *telling you* that the shape will no longer be a live shape. Are you missing that warning?

Once the live shape is expanded, there is no way to revert it to a primitive other than to redraw the shape with the Shape Tool so it is a primitive again.

**Important Additional**: Shape editing tools are only seen when a **Shape Tool** is the **active** tool. ***Switching to the Shape Tool will show the properties for live shapes again.***

Comment: ah. thanks for your post. `live shapes` term I haven't heard before :D This will help me a lot for future learning. Here is two points:
1. I try to transform and meet the warning as you see. thanks for your post, I understand why.
2. Yes. Now, if I choose again `Shape Tool` for that layer, I can see `shape toolbar` again :D But about Live  Shape Properties` (my second image), I still don't see it. Do you know why ? 
Thanks :)

Comment: If you don't see the shape properties with the Shape Tool active, then the shape is not a live shape. With the Move Tool active you never see *any* shape properties.

Comment: I don't edit anything yet, just draw and select other layers and select again shape layer. Does this action will lost `live shape` attribute ? I have added 4th image to my question. This image is show when I select again shape layer. Please review it. Do I do something wrong ? Thanks :)

Comment: I think you may be missing you **can not** use the **Move Tool**. You **must** use a **Shape Tool**.

Comment: Can you recheck again in my 5th image I have uploaded. As you see in this image, I have a `shape layer` is a pink rectangle. I also selected `Shape tool` as you see in left toolbar. You can see `Shape Tool` on top screen also, but at `properties`, it just appears `mask` rather than `live shape attribute`. Thanks :)

Comment: Ahhh. I understand. `live shape attribute` just can be showed when I select `Path Select Tool` :D I think this thing is confuse. Because when I draw a shape, just `Shape tool` highlight and not `Path Select Tool`. Base on link @Joonas under my question, I can understand why. Thanks for helping me. Your knowledge is valuable to me :D I just I don't know can I get those information (about `live shape` for example) in any books ? Thanks :)